# cant retreive the documents in my firebase using documents.length

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys im learning flutter and i have an error whenever i try to call documents in the listbuilder it gives me an error but when i tried it on a floatingactionbutton to get my texts it worked fine instead of documents i used docs it worked but for this one it doesnt work out so please help me im trying to get item counts here's my full code below

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/Dx7QFvCELN2XFWumVWOY/messages')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
          return new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.documents.length, //the error is in here
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text("This Works"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please change the title to describe a summary of your issue

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: i have commented the place i got the error ive got it in the                             
 itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.documents.length,

Comment: Okay, but what is the actual error you get?

Comment: the error is at documents

Comment: Can you copy the error message in here?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting a null pointer exception. Initially the `builder` function is called before the data is returned from Firestore. You can check for that and display another Widget while there isn't any data yet:

```
builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
  if(!streamSnapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
  return new ListView.builder(
```

Also, I think you might need to use `docs` instead of `documents`. The type of `streamSnapshot` should be `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` and according to the [documentation of QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), there's only a `docs` getter.

Comment: i still have the error ive been searching for two days and still didnt find any solutions

Comment: update the answer, you might need to use 'docs' instead of 'documents'

Comment: i already used docs it didnt work out and anywwheres my error code :                                  Error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:18
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'.
            itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.documents.length,

Comment: Looking at the documentation, there isn't a `documents` getter, only a `docs` getter

Comment: i managed to fix it i just addedd StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> and everything worked thanks for your time bro

Comment: Alright, good to hear. Best of luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: Thank youuuu brooo :)